# External GPU card for iMac

Tags: graphics-cards

I have an iMac 27 (core i5, 8gb ram, AMD Radeon R9 M290X 2gb) and this is not enough for some new games. So are there external graphics card box, which capable of operate on the internal monitor iMac with windows OS?

I know about Sonnet, Akitio and Bizon adapters, but it works only on external monitor.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use an external GPU to run the built in monitor without some modification. Usually devices with built in screens use proprietary connectors. E.g. a laptop. I think you're going to have a hard time converting the GPU video out (HDMI, VGA etc...) to whatever the proprietary connector is.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to be the same deal as Sonnet, Akitio, and Bizon, but have you taken a look at the [Razer Core](http://www.razerzone.com/store/razer-core)? It requires a Thunderbolt 3 port, but it might work for your AIO Mac.